# Need to reduce run time on creating a list of numbers based on a formula and a number n

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need a better way to create a list of numbers, so that the run time is less. Or probably figure out a better approach to my problem.

I'm running a code to create a series of numbers based on 2 formulas. Starting from 1, the formulas create the following numbers. The idea is to return the number n from the list that is created at the end. Even tough the formulas create the same number in some cases, only unique values remain, and the list is sorted to match. I use a while loop to create the list, and I believe that reducing the number of repetitions can help with my problem, but I can't figure out a way to effectively reduce it, without ruining the purpose of my code.

```
def dbl_linear(n):
    x = 1
    y = 0
    z = 0
    i = 0
    u = []
    u.append(x)
    while i <= n:
        x = (u)[i]
        y = 2 * x + 1
        u.append(y)
        z = 3 * x + 1
        u.append(z)
        i = i + 1
        u.sort()
    uFix = set(u)
    uFix = list(uFix)
    uFix.sort()
    return uFix[n]
print(dbl_linear(50))
```

These are the expected results. Which I get, but it takes too long.

```
dbl_linear(10), 22)
dbl_linear(20), 57)
dbl_linear(30), 91)
dbl_linear(50), 175)
```

Comment: Is there really a need to sort the list every single time inside while, instead of sorting it only once after all numbers are generated? It seems you don't need an input from the list inside while, so the order should not matter at that point?

Comment: Isn't `x = (u)[i]` requiring the list to be sorted?

Comment: Do you need the result for only one large number or you need to call your function many times for different values?

Comment: I tested the code without sorting and it is noticeably faster. Initially I considered that it was necessary, since it is a linear (sort of) progression, but it seems that I can do without it due to only needing the generated number to generate two others, and it doesn't need to be in order, since it gets ordered at the end.

Comment: The function it's used to call only one number at time. Say that the input is 50, it should return the 50th value on the list, after generating the linear progression (and deleting duplicates and sorting again).

Comment: I understand that it's for one number at a time, my question is Do you need `dbl_linear(n)` for only one big value of `n`, or do you need it for multiple values,  e.g. `50`, `126`, `382`, `97`, ... If you know the maximum value you ever need to compute you can compute it only once but keep the list in memory, then all smaller values will be accessible instantly...

Comment: Ah got it, it is for multiple values. It can be any number really, there is no specified max number

Comment: You can still keep it in memory to start over where you left instead of starting again from scratch...

Comment: @stephenrauch `x = (u)[i]` assumes always the last _i_ position. Also values are appended to the end of list, so what lies before them on the list does not matter, so there should not be a need to sort the list, as you are doing insane amount of extra work, sorting in every iteration.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was noticing some inconsistencies in my results with big inputs (n). It seems that taking out the inner sort, tough speeds up the run time, generates differences. For example, without the inner sort n==100 should return 447, but instead returns 471. Leaving the inner sort does indeed return 447. Is there a way to optimize the code with the inner sort?

Comment: @StackingForHeap, two things.  Sorting an almost sorted is generally not as expensive as a total sort.  And the loop adds two element each time, so why is `x = u[i]` the end of the list?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes, not as expensive but quite taxing still. Rather than being at the _end of the list_ it's (by his code) at the last _i-position_, which also has direct relation to his Z and Y values. The last round's Z becomes new X. If this were not linear, it would be whole another case. As in: if you generate random numbers and need the highest number on top of index. Very inefficient code anyways, your actual answer +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can be considerably simplified to:

#### Code:

```
def dbl_linear(n):
    u = [1]
    for i in range(n):
        x = u[i]
        u.extend((2 * x + 1, 3 * x + 1))
    return sorted(set(u))[n]
```

#### Test Code:

```
assert dbl_linear(10) == 22
assert dbl_linear(20) == 57
assert dbl_linear(30) == 91
assert dbl_linear(50) == 175
```